# how to show the sql query in different page?

Tags: php, mysql, html

how to show the sql query in different page?(using php)
like when link 1 is clicked then 1-10 will appear ..
for 2 it is 11-20 and so on..

Comment: This is called "pagination", see ["pagination in php"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060399/pagination-in-php) and [many others](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+%5Bsql%5D+pagination).

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking like something like:

- page1.php?show=10 (1-10)
- page1.php?show=20 (11-20)

You'll have to do some calculations (max # of page, start & end of resultset) and then use the LIMIT clause if you're using mysql.

Answer (score 0):

The "Easiest" approach is to add the LIMIT clause to your query and pass in the page number.
so if page number is 1 (i.e. the default or first page)

```
$page = 1;
$query = "SELECT * FROM Product WHERE name LIKE 'John%' LIMIT ";

if($page == 1){

   $query .= $recordsPerPage;

}

else{

   $query .= ($recordsPerPage+1) ."," ($page-1 + $recordsPerPage);

}
```

You'll need to execute a separate query to get the number of matching records and divide them by the records per page.

only an acceptable approach for a not high traffic site.
High traffic sites you'll probably have to use cursors.

Answer (score 0):

As Ali mentioned, the easiest approach is to LIMIT your query, and build the number of pages depending on the total count in the DB.

You may find this useful

http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/29.html

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking at MySQL's `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`.

And a simple example:

```
// parameters
$ipp = 10; # items per page
$page = $_GET['page']; # lets fetch page from clicked link
if(!$page){ $page = 1; } # default page to be used when none is given (to be used when we're at index.php
$offset = ($page - 1) * $ipp; # lets calculate result offset for current page

// query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` LIMIT {$ipp} OFFSET {$offset};";
// add your desired result processing
```

Links for this example are as simple as: `index.php?page=1`, `index.php?page=2` etc.