# Spring mvc pagination

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, pagination

Hello I'm using jqgrid for my project, and I needed to implement the pagination so I found a code in php and copied it over to java :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "getgriddata", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody
    String getGrid(@RequestParam("page") String page, @RequestParam("rows") int rownumber, @RequestParam("sidx") String sortBy, @RequestParam("sord") String sortOrder,@RequestParam(value = "_search") String search, @RequestParam(value="filters", required = false) String filters) {

        int totalCount = dao.getTotalRecordCount();

        CustomJsonResponse response = new CustomJsonResponse();

        int totalPages = 0;

        if (totalCount > 0) {
            totalPages = (int) Math.ceil(totalCount/rownumber);
        }

        if (Integer.valueOf(page) > totalPages) {
            page = String.valueOf(totalPages);
        }

        Gson jsonConverter = new Gson();

        int start = (rownumber * Integer.valueOf(page)) - rownumber;
        Filters searchFilter = null;

        if(Boolean.valueOf(search) == true){
            searchFilter = jsonConverter.fromJson(filters, Filters.class);
        }

        // Retrieve records from database
        List<Record> recorBatch = dao.getRecords(start, rownumber, sortBy, sortOrder, search, searchFilter);

        // Assign the result from the service to this response
        response.setRows(recorBatch);
        response.setTotal(String.valueOf(totalPages));
        response.setRecords(String.valueOf(stagingLoadBatch.size()));
        response.setPage(page);

        return jsonConverter.toJson(response);
    }
```

This works ok when I'm working with entire set of data, but when I narrow the search, i.e. select records in some time interval, then the pagination breaks down. I realized this is bad practice, I've copied it from this code for pagination:

http://pastebin.com/ybKSXzyq

Can anybody suggest better solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you to look at [`Display Tag Library`](http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/), for pagination.

Comment: I'm using jqgrid not display library, tx

Comment: @London: Yes, but it seems to me that it is not solving your pagination problem, as you yourself mentioned that you hacked with PHP code. So, why not go for something Java?

Comment: because I'm almost done with the project but didn't give any though to this pagination, thought it was working all along I can't switch all of logic now.

Comment: found the correct solution by the way again from php, correct this time http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060399/pagination-in-php

Comment: @London: Good to know that. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing full implementation of it I did JQGridPage.java class to contain data for jqgrid as

```
public class JQGridPage<T> {

    private Integer page;
    private Integer total;
    private Long records;
    private List<T> rows;
....
}
```

and in controller method I'm filling it and send it as return of method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET, params = "page")
@ResponseBody
public JQGridPage<T> listPages(
        @RequestParam(value = "page", defaultValue = "1") int page,
        @RequestParam(value = "rows", defaultValue = "10") int rows,
        @RequestParam(value = "sidx", defaultValue = "id") String sortField,
        @RequestParam(value = "sord", defaultValue = "ASC") String sortDirection,
        @RequestParam(value = "searchField", defaultValue = "id") String searchField,
        @RequestParam(value = "searchOper", defaultValue = "eq") String searchOper,
        @RequestParam(value = "searchString", defaultValue = "") String searchString) {
.....
    JQGridPage<T> jqGrid = new JQGridPage<T>();
    jqGrid.setPage(page);
    jqGrid.setTotal(pageOfCustomer.getTotalPages());
    jqGrid.setRecords(pageOfCustomer.getTotalElements());
    jqGrid.setRows(pageOfCustomer.getContent());
    return jqGrid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my pangination result in Spring MVC
[image: image1]

[image: image2]

[image: image3]