# echo MySQL array records one by one in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, echo

I would like to know how to `echo` an array records one by one with button click to print both forward and revers records.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM printingorder WHERE recHead = 'Pending'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

if I used

```
while($postate = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
    echo  "<h4>" .'1. Faculty : '. $postate['facultyId'] ."</h4>";
    echo  "<h4>" .'2. Department : '. $postate['departmentId'] ."</h4>";
    echo  "<h4>" .'3. Programm : '. $postate['programmId'] ."</h4>";
}
```

it prints all records after each raw contents.But I need only one complete raw content and next raw with button click(or hyperlink) for both forward and revers array records.

Comment: Note: Don't write new code with the `mysql_*` functions. They are becoming deprecated and will be removed from future PHP versions. Use `mysqli_*` or PDO instead.

Comment: You will have to use a parameter in your link that tells the php page how many rows to skip. This way you can add this to your query and show the requested row.

Comment: possible duplicate of [pagination in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060399/pagination-in-php)

Comment: Thank you for immediate response and i'l use mysqli_* for coding in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query should be like this :

```
$a = $_POST['row_number'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM printingorder WHERE recHead = 'Pending' limit $a,1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

On both button( previuos and  next) post interger value which is row number. for previous decrement value and for next increment value.

Comment: Thank you very much Mr.Mahipat Kanzariya. its works. this kinds of helps are very useful to my project works.

Comment: Hi @Sujeewahms, If you like such a answer in stackoverflow then please vote and select as best answer rather than just saying thanks in comment.

Comment: Sorry dear. I already voted you but it says "Vote up requires 15 reps".I joined just today and when I achieved that requirement, you will be the first person i will vote.

Answer (score -1):

`

```
 while($postate = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
    echo  "<h4>" .'1. Faculty : '. $postate['facultyId'] ."</h4>";
    echo  "<h4>" .'2. Department : '. $postate['departmentId'] ."</h4>";
    echo  "<h4>" .'3. Programm : '. $postate['programmId'] ."</h4>";
}
```

`

Try with mysql_fetch_assoc

Comment: -1: This answer has nothing to do with the question.